# Updating WatchKit app when containing iOS app's data changes

Tags: ios, notifications, updates, watchkit

I've been reading the [Apple Watch Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/) and I made some examples of requesting data from the `WatchKit` extension to the containing app and getting back the result. But what if I want to communicate in the opposite direction? I mean, let's say I have my iOS app in foreground and I refresh there some data, and then I want the `WatchKit` app to update its user interface according to its paired iOS app just refreshed data. How could I do this? Should I launch a local notification from the iOS app to the `WatchKit` app and then request the new data from it, or is there any other (and better) way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To notify Watch App from the iOS application for data changes, you can do so manually by using the Darwin notification center.

More reference here:
https://devforums.apple.com/message/1082630#1082630

Darwin notification center:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/MacOSXNotifcationOv/DarwinNotificationConcepts/DarwinNotificationConcepts.html